# <ul><li> indent problems

Tags: html, css

How am I suppose to remove the indent from my unordered list. when inspecting element i can see what looks like padding being that it is between the width of the box and the content, but setting padding to 0px and margin to 0px does nothing the list starts further into the header than it should. what do? is this a common problem?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the example?

Comment: Can you post some code, please, and tell us which browser you're using?

Comment: show some code, you've probably forgotten to remove the margin or padding from the `ul` or `li` element.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a 16 or 40px margin?

Answer (score 6):

Add:

```
UL, LI
{ padding:0px; margin:0px }
```

To both the UL and the LI elements

Comment: I had already tried this, it didn't work. I resolved the problem by putting a negative margin on the left hand side. not exactly what I wanted but it works

Comment: I didn't use a comma to separate ul from li. Applying to both now works.

Answer (score 4):

All browsers ship with certain basic stylesheets that provide basic formatting for common elements. I'm assuming you haven't overridden all of those stylesheet definitions for your list, so you could include a so-called reset stylesheet - the one from Eric Meyer is very popular: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ - or further inspect what is formatting your list by using tools such as Firebug for Firefox or Dragonfly for Opera.

Comment: Yes. Most resets will include what's needed here, which, as @Chris says, is almost certainly to zero the padding and margin on both `ul` and `li` elements. It's worth learning about and using a reset stylesheet, as different browsers will apply their styles in different ways, and a well-established reset should help you avoid surprises. Mind you, if *all* you need turns out to be the list styling, a reset is overkill.

Comment: I agree and personally use Eric Meyer's listed above.  If you are working on an existing project that you have a lot of time into you may not want to use a reset sheet but I would highly recommend one in the future.  It is the first thing I add to any new project.

Comment: ill give this a little go. atm Im using a negative margin to equal it out but I don't really like the messiness that is elements sticking out all over the place. ill try this and get back to you